# attribute comparision using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am having huge xml file like this:

```
  <List NAME="ANDREW" ENROLED="2" FEE="640" CONFORMATION="I"> 
     <DATA>
       <HOUSE>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37496" SECTION="A"/>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37496" SECTION="B"/>
       </HOUSE>
      </DATA>
     </List>
     <List NAME="SAM" ENROLED="4" FEE="640"  CONFORMATION="O">
      <DATA>
       <HOUSE>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36816" SECTION="A"/>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36816" SECTION="B"/>
       </HOUSE>
      </DATA>
     </List>
     <List NAME="RAY" ENROLED="1" FEE="982"   CONFORMATION="O">
      <ADDRESS>
       <STREET>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="A"/>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="B"/>
       </STREET>
      </ADDRESS>
     </List>
      <List NAME="MATHEW" ENROLED="3" FEE="467" CONFORMATION="I">
     <DATA>
       <HOUSE>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37436" SECTION="A"/>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37436" SECTION="B"/>
       </HOUSE>
      </DATA>
     </List>
     <List NAME="RAY" ENROLED="1" FEE="982"   CONFORMATION="O">
      <ADDRESS>
       <STREET>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="A"/>
        <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="B"/>
       </STREET>
      </ADDRESS>
     </List>
```

i have to print the value of "FEE" and "GROUP_ID" if the CONFORMATION IS "O" and if the conformation is "I" i have to print that in separate line.

i have used following program i got help for this

```
XML::Twig;

my $phraser = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {API_PORT => \&process_list});
$phraser -> parsefile("FS_CONF.xml");

sub process_list 
{
    my ( $twig, $list ) = @_;
    my $conformation = $list -> att( 'LIST' ); 

 my $fee = $list -> att ( 'FEE' );
    foreach my $primary ( $list -> first_child ( 'DATA' ) -> first_child ('HOUSE') -> children() )
    {
        my $group_id = $primary -> att ( 'GROUP_ID' );
        print "$conformation, $fee, $group_id\n";

    }

}
```

after getting printed two values
it is showing error because all the tags are not same and showing error 
can't call method first child on undefined value.

this is comming because of all the "first_child" are not similar.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

Change your handler to `List`.

Use `CONFORMATION` for `$conformation`.

Check for the `DATA` tag with `defined`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $phraser = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { List => \&process_list } );
$phraser->parsefile("FS_CONF.xml");

sub process_list {
    my ( $twig, $list ) = @_;
    my $conformation = $list->att('CONFORMATION');
    my $fee = $list->att('FEE');
    if (defined $list->first_child('DATA')) {
        foreach my $primary ( $list->first_child('DATA')->first_child('HOUSE')->children() ) {
            my $group_id = $primary->att('GROUP_ID');
            print "$conformation, $fee, $group_id\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i got the output correctly.
if i want to extract one more data which is at "DATA" "size" .
then how can i manage both the branch .
example (List NAME="MATHEW" ENROLED="3" FEE="467" CONFORMATION="I")
     (DATA size ="128")
       (HOUSE)
        (PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37436" SECTION="A"/)
thank you for replying